# Spring Integration Sending Files to Remote Directory

Tags: spring-boot, ftp, spring-integration

I am trying to send files from my local directory to a remote directory by FTP,
and could able to send the files successfully, but additionally the files are being FTP'ed to the local directory, since the ftpInbound is also establishing a FTP connection, which i don't want my application to do. If I remove  inbound FTP channel adapter, couldn't feed the local directory path to the ftpOutbound also. Are there any other ways to resolve this problem ?

```
<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="ftpInbound"
                                channel="ftpChannel" 
                                session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
                                filename-pattern="*.txt"
                                local-directory="$dina-communication.batch-{localDirectory}"
                                temporary-file-suffix=".writing">
<int:poller fixed-rate="10000" />

</int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter  id="ftpOutbound"
                                channel="ftpChannel" 
                                session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
                                remote-directory="$dina-communication.batch-{Remote_directory}"
                                temporary-file-suffix=".writing">
</int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you talk about feeding *local* directory content to the FTP server, you should consider to use really `<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/files.html#file-reading

There is also a sample on the matter: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/file

You should replace your `<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>` with just a `<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>`.

Comment: columnNumber: 43; The prefix "int-file" for element "int-file:inbound-channel-adapter" is not bound.
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)                                                                    ---Im getting the above error , int-file couldnt match with int-ftp , since my outbound directory is a Remote Server . Will it work for remote server also ?

Comment: You should have `spring-integration-file` in your classpath and have a proper XSD definition. You can find that in the sample provided: `http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd`